# Consulta SQL que atenda a um parâmetro que é um conjunto

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho a seguinte situação: em uma CONSULTA MÉDICA posso ter um ou mais SINTOMAS. Logo tenho uma tabela CONSULTA_SINTOMA, fazendo a ligação entre CONSULTA e SINTOMA. Uma doença pode ser identificada por um ou mais sintomas, logo tenho uma tabela DOENÇA_SINTOMA fazendo a ligação entre DOENÇA e SINTOMA.

Meu problema: consigo obter na tabela CONSULTA todas os ids dos sintomas apresentados em uma consulta. Mas como fazer para, a partir daí, saber todas as possíveis doenças? Por exemplo: se os sintomas apresentados em uma consulta forem: 1, 2 e 3. Como saber quais doenças são identificadas por esses sintomas?

Comment: Você quer as doenças com os 3 sintomas, ou pelo menos um dos 3?

Comment: Com os 3 sintomas.

Comment: @AllexandreJr da uma olhada na minha alteração

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso. Uma de que gosto bastante usa um `GROUP BY` e o conhecimento prévio de quantos sintomas você precisa casar.

Um exemplo, supondo a estrutura real das sua base de dados:

```
SELECT
    Doenca.*

FROM CONSULTA_SINTOMA cs

    INNER JOIN DOENCA_SINTOMA ds
    ON ds.sintoma_id = cs.sintoma_id
    INNER JOIN DOENCA Doenca
    ON Doenca.id = ds.doenca_id

WHERE cs.consulta_id = 1  -- a consulta
AND cs.sintoma_id IN (1,2,3) -- os sintomas

GROUP BY Doenca.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- porque são 3 sintomas
```

---

Uma variação mais curta, que não requer passar os sintomas explicitamente, mas ainda requer saber quantos são:

```
SELECT
    Doenca.*
FROM DOENCA_SINTOMA ds
    INNER JOIN DOENCA Doenca
    ON Doenca.id = ds.doenca_id
WHERE ds.sintoma_id IN (
   SELECT sintoma_id FROM CONSULTA_SINTOMA
   WHERE consulta_id = 1 -- a consulta
) -- os sintomas

GROUP BY Doenca.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- porque são 3 sintomas
```

Comment: @bfavarreto Eu tinha tentado o IN, mas, ele retorna as doenças que tem pelo menos 1 dos sintomas. Qdo preciso das doenças que possuem todos os sintomas.

Comment: Tente essa query inteira. O agrupamento + `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` garante que só venham as que têm os 3 sintomas.

Comment: É verdade @bfavaretto não prestei atenção no having. Acho que assim dá. Vou testar pra ver. ;)

Comment: Funcionou @bfavaretto. Só fiz trocar os sintomas pelo respectivo select.

Comment: Que bom, @AllexandreJr! Depois de reler meu código, vi que dá para simplificar a query, de modo que só precise passar o id da consulta. Vou atualizar a resposta em breve.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei como está suas colunas, mas tentei deduzir que as chaves são ID_TABELA.

### A doença ter pelo menos um sintoma:

```
  SELECT CO.ID_CONSULTA, SI.ID_SINTOMA, DO.ID_DOENCA FROM CONSULTA CO
    INNER JOIN CONSULTA_SINTOMA CS ON CO.ID_CONSULTA = CS.ID_CONSULTA
    INNER JOIN SINTOMA SI ON CS.ID_SINTOMA = SI.ID_SINTOMA
    INNER JOIN DOENCA_SINTOMA DS ON SI.ID_SINTOMA = DS.ID_SINTOMA
    INNER JOIN DOENCA DO ON DS.ID_DOENCA = DO.ID_DOENCA
```

Para cada doença vai repetir o sintoma e consulta, você só precisa trocar os campos que quer trazer no `SELECT`.

### A doença ter todos os sintomas: (Utilizando o operador [ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html))

```
  SELECT * FROM DOENCA DO
    INNER JOIN DOENCA_SINTOMA DS ON DO.ID_DOENCA = DS.ID_DOENCA
    WHERE DS.ID_SINTOMA = ALL (SELECT CS.ID_SINTOMA 
                               FROM CONSULTA_SINTOMA CS
                               WHERE CS.ID_CONSULTA = x)
```

`x` será seu código da consulta

- Query feita no MySQL 5.5.32

Comment: Maicon, assim está retornando as doenças que são identificas por pelo menos 1 dos sintomas. Eu preciso daquelas que são identificadas por todos os sintomas.

Comment: @AllexandreJr eu atualizei o código de acordo com sua condição.

Comment: Opa @Maicon Carraro, mesmo nesse segundo caso, me retorna as consultas que tem pelo menos 1 dos sintomas.

Comment: @AllexandreJr retorna as consultas ou doenças com 1 dos sintomas?

Comment: Desculpe, @Maicon Carrado. Retorna as doenças. Mas já consegui resolver seguindo o exemplo do bfavaretto. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não testei.
Resposta rápida para que você possa testar:

```
SELECT SI.doencaId FROM sintomas SI    
WHERE SI.sintomasId IN (
  SELECT CO_SI.sintomasID FROM consultas_sintomas CO_SI 
  WHERE CO_SI.consultaId = id
)
```

`id` - id da consulta para a qual você quer saber as possíveis doenças

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve criar uma tabela doenças e outra de sintomas e então uma de relacionamento entre doenças e sintomas.
Para as consultas você deve fazer algo pareciso, uma de consultas e outra de relacionamento sintomas-consultas.

Dai fica fácil descobrir quais doenças apresentam os n sintomas.

Obs:Espero que esta seja uma pergunta "retórica" e não com o objetivo de criar um sistema de diagnósticos.